# How do I edit an xmlTV file using sed (or a similar tool)?

Tags: command-line, mysql, regex, sed

I have an xmlTV file that looks like this:

```
<channel id="10125.dvb.guide" <!-- number="62" type="0x1" flags="0xf" bouquet="4097" region="4a" sid="10125" -->>
<display-name>ITV +1</display-name>
```

I want to edit it so that I can automatically pull info from it for importing into MySQL.

```
update channel set channum="62" where callsign="ITV +1";
update channel set xmltvid="10125.dvb.guide" where callsign="ITV +1";
```

I have tried:

```
sed 's/<!-- number=/update channel set channum=/g'
sed 's/<channel id=/update update channel set xmltvid=/g'
```

but this really flies right over my head, any hints or tips would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use v5.14;
use warnings;

until(eof()) {
    my ($id, $chan) = <> =~ /id="([^"]*)".*number="(\d+)"/;
    my ($sign) = <> =~ />(.*)</;
    <>; # Skip </channel>

    say qq(UPDATE channel SET channum="$chan",xmltvid="$id" WHERE callsign="$sign");
}
```

You could also use DBI to edit the database directly from the script.

Comment: ok jumped the gun a little here! It extracts fine with one line, but when its multiple ( http://pastie.org/10178373 ) it only does the first one. How can i get it to repeat to go through a whole file ?

Comment: I've edited the answer to support files with multiple entries